# SQL Server Stored Procedure Error Handling - Linked Server Down

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling

I currently have a stored procedure on my web server for our asp.net website that calls a remote stored procedure on our accounting system, a separate linked server, to return inventory information for a product. In the rare chance our accounting system is down, I want to employ error handling so the product page does not hang when the remote stored procedure execution fails.

So in the case that the remote server is offline or cannot be reached for any reason, I want the stored procedure on the website to return a default selection. Is this possible?

Comment: one way is there. each time while u connect linked server to execute some query save that query result in local server or any other server that can accessable.
and delete that query result when the query execute subsequent.  So if query execute fails on linked server you can mak use of local server result.

Comment: SQL Server supports try...catch blocks, so it should be possible to handle the error. about returning the default selection, that depends on what that selection is.